# regex issue in extract M followed by 8 digits

Tags: excel, regex, vba, regexp-replace

excel value=`M#9094562;M 0567468;M25969028;M25969029;Mployee e`

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim strOutput As String
    
strPattern = "m[0-9]{8}"
    
    
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""
        
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With
        
        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex tester to check what you are getting. https://regexr.com/

Your current Regex only matches 2 occurrences in your pattern.

[image]

The others contain a space and a hash, and one only has 7 digits.  If you want to find these as well you can expand your pattern.

m.?[0-9]{7,8}

[image]

But, if you truly want M followed by 8 digits (M12345678) then your pattern works.

Your Excel code is wrong... you are not looping through the matches (see below):

```
If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
    simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
Else
```

You need to loop through the matches in the string (see below):

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String

'Added to store matches
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim strDelimiter As String
intCounter = 1
strDelimiter = "|"

strPattern = "m[0-9]{8}"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        
        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        
            'Store matched string and loop through matches
            Set objRegMC = regEx.Execute(strInput)

            For Each objRegM In objRegMC
                'Do what you want here to split values etc.
                'I have added a delimiter, you can do whatever you want
                
                If objRegMC.Count > 1 Then
                    If intCounter = objRegMC.Count Then
                        simpleCellRegex = simpleCellRegex & objRegM
                    Else
                        simpleCellRegex = simpleCellRegex & objRegM & strDelimiter
                    End If
                    intCounter = intCounter + 1
                Else
                    simpleCellRegex = objRegM
                End If
            Next
      
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
        
    End If
End Function
```

Results below:

[image]

Comment: when i try to use this code regex m[0-9]{8}
Result :- M#9094562;M 0567468;;;Mployee e 
but we have want result (M25969028;M25969029) only M followed by 8 digits.

Comment: Can you add an image showing the excel range?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comment.  You were not looping through the matches in the string.

Comment: You are welcome.  If it solved your issue, you can upvote the post and mark as the answer.